# Can you use a String in place of a variable name?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Simply put, can you take a value stored as a String and cast it as a variable name?

Condensed, this is the functionality I would be looking for

```
let a = 5
let str = "a"

print(magicFunction(str))
```

which would print the value of a.

Some uses would be using button names or user input to access variables without conditional loops.

Comment: The linked duplicate is very slightly different, but addresses the question you're asking. Since that answer, Swift has added KeyPaths, which are a powerful way to dynamically access properties, and dynamic members, which even allows strings to be turned into properties. But there is somewhat by design nothing that looks like what you're describing here. What would be the return type of `magicFunction`? What would happen if you passed a name that didn't exist? If you have a specific use case, there are generally very good approaches that don't require crashing on mistakes.

Comment: addressing nil is a common process, I didn't want to bog down the example. I don't know if there's a 'variable name' (likely not) but I thought I would see if someone knew something I didn't (likely on all accounts). I am looking for more tools to choose from.

Comment: Specific variables may not even exist at runtime (it is very common for variables to be optimized out entirely, and local variables in particular often do not need to store their names in the final executable in a fully optimized build). So you'll need to discuss a specific use-case. For example, dynamic members will allow you to treat strings as if they were properties, but you need to provide code that decides what to do with that string. If you need to convert strings into values, you generally really mean a Dictionary, not variables.

Comment: I am aware my question most likely does not have an answer for the reasons you mentioned, and there are well-used patterns to do the the same thing I am looking into. But I do mean variable. For example, if a user was tracking some data and had buttons to print the value of a, b, c. If I could pass the name of the button as the name of the variable, it could be a single line in a single IBAction func. I'm always looking for more options to do something, you never know when a nugget turns into a gem.

Comment: In that case this is definitely a duplicate. The linked answer should give you the information you need. As you expect, the answer is no. Best of luck.

Comment: Disappointing, but expected. Thanks for the response (not sarcastic).